# activityIndicator in UIWebView with TabBar

Tags: uiwebview, uitabbar, uiactivityindicatorview

I hope some one can help me with that.

I have a TabBar with some WebViews and an activityIndicator for each side.
how can I hide this one when the side is Loaded?

I tryed it with

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{
      NSLog(@"Start test");
      [activityIndicator startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1{
      NSLog(@"Stop test");
     [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
     [activityIndicator hidesWhenStopped];
}
```

but the function dosen't even get called.

I placed them in the ViewController where the webView is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made your class the delegate for UIWebView?

```
[webview setDelegate:self];
```

You should also declare your class as a delegate:

```
@interface ClassName : NSObject <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Except UIWebView :**

```
[pActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(fnWillCall) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
[pActivityIndicatorView startanimating];
[pActivityIndicatorView stopanimating];
```

**UIWebView :**

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
       [pActivityIndicatorView startAnimating];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
       [pActivityIndicatorView stopAnimating];
}
```